# Setting CSS with JavaScript/jQuery forces unwanted double quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make a `background-image` CSS property have the value `url('img.jpg')`

What I do:

```
<div id="mDiv" style="background-image: url('img2.jpg')" ></div>
```

..

```
$("#mDiv").css("background-image","url('img.jpg')");
```

OR without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("mDiv").style.backgroundImage = "url('img.jpg')";
```

Result:

```
<div id="mDiv" style="background-image: url("img.jpg")" ></div>
```

Wanted result:

```
<div id="mDiv" style="background-image: url('img.jpg')" ></div>
```

(I also tried making style='...', but it gets converted to double quotes too... What can I do to get the wanted result?)

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your code. That's just the way the browser's DOM viewer displays attributes.

Comment: Are you having a problem because of the quoting?

Comment: There is no need for the quotes in the url. You can just use `background-image: url(img2.jpg)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("mDiv").style.backgroundImage = "url('img.jpg')";
```

What you need to understand is that the content of your page in the browser is not stored as a string of markup. The page is a hierarchy of objects and properties.

When you execute the above, or the equivalent versions with `setAttribute`/`attr()` the other answers are suggesting, the browser is not necessarily storing a string `url('img.jpg')` anywhere: it's parsing it to extract the url `img.jpg`, and keeping *that*. The information about whether you used single quotes, double quotes or no quotes at all to wrap the URL is gone forever.

If you then ask for a serialised form of that as markup, for example by reading the `style` attribute or grabbing the `innerHTML` of the document, the browser has to recreate some markup from the properties it has. The browser can choose all sorts of arbitrary ways to serialise that data as long as the output represents the same document content.

There is no reason to expect the output will look much like the markup you put in. In particular, the browser may choose different single or double quote delimiters; it may order attributes differently; it may include different whitespace; and so on.

```
Result:
<div id="mDiv" style="background-image: url("img.jpg")" ></div>
```

This, however, is not valid HTML, because of the nested quotes. I think you are looking at the element in the DOM Inspector, which in some browsers doesn't necessarily show you an HTML-valid output. If you get the parent element's `innerHTML` I think you will see the inner quotes escaped to `&quot;`.

Comment: But the image doesn't show up, and once I edit the double quotes to single quotes it shows up (yes through the developer tool in Chrome)

Comment: @RedStar , try my answer!

Comment: You have some different problem. Setting `backgroundImage` to `url('img.jpg')` or `url("img.jpg")` is absolutely identical, according to the CSS standard and every browser.

Comment: YES! I'm sorry for the mistake. Now it works even with the invalid markup because I didn't know that the developer console just recreates the content on the fly. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#mDiv").css("background-image","url(img.jpg)");
```

Comment: Result: `<div id="mDiv" style="background-image: url("img.jpg")" ></div>`
So it's not working, still adds the double quotes inside url()

Comment: Check example here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5HDu/308/)
Just as a note, you'll not get single quotes anywhere in your HTML. The browsers standardize everything to be in double quotes. Unless in a sentence...But not as part of the HTML formatting, so there's literally nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `attr` like this:

```
$("#mDiv").attr({style:"background-image: url(img.jpg)"});
```

Final code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div {
                width: 200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="mDiv" style="background-image:url(http://godfatherstyle.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/water-drops-on-flowers-wallpapers.jpg)" >Ehsan</div>
        <button>Change</button>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("button").on("click",function(){
                    $("#mDiv").attr({style:"background-image:url(http://godfatherstyle.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Colourful_Flower_01.jpg)"});
                })
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do that

```
$("#mDiv").attr({style:"background-image: url('img.jpg')"});
```

Comment: I DID NOT DOWNVOTE !!! (and yes it's working, expect that it messes the rest of the style attribute ..
Result : `<div style="background-image: url('img.jpg')" ');background-size:="" cover;background-position:="" center="" center;'=""> </div>` )

Answer (score 0):

Try using the backslash escape character \ or using a separate variable to get to the root of the problem:

$('mDiv').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');